# Libreoffice3.5 applications opening in new icon

Tags: launcher, libreoffice, icons

Whenever I open a program from Libreoffice3.5, it will open with its own launcher icon. For example, if I click on my docked "Writer", it will open in another icon.

[image]

I've also noticed that these opened icons are very blurry too... Any one have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I have found a solution, one that works for me at least.

The same thing was happening to my Chromium icon on the launcher. I fixed it by getting rid of the icon, opening the Dash (windows button), searching for chromium, and then dragging the chromium icon from the dash to the launcher.

Do **not** add it to the launcher by opening the application and then right clicking the icon and selecting **lock to launcher**. I tried that, and it results in the same double-icon problem as before.

Comment: I've actually solved the problem by simply installing the newest stable LibreOffice install. But, this fix does make sense! :) I'm accepting the answer to show that this is a valid way to make it work.